# Java code freezing mid execution

Tags: java

Im running my code, and after it says the first print statement it pauses. It pauses at a point where it calls a function "insert" and simply doesnt respond anything. it prints "adding dog, cat, & horse" but then just stops, doesnt do anything after that.

main function

```
package assignment2;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        OrderedStringList myList = new OrderedStringList(5);

        System.out.println("adding dog, cat, & horse");
        myList.Insert("dog");
        myList.Insert("cat");
        myList.Insert("horse");

        myList.Display();

        System.out.println("Value pig find = "+ myList.Find("pig"));
        System.out.println("Value horse find = "+ myList.Find("horse"));

        System.out.println("Adding mouse & rat");
        myList.Insert("mouse");
        myList.Insert("rat");

        myList.Display();

        System.out.println("myList size: "+ myList.Size());

        if (!myList.Insert("chinchilla"))
            System.out.println("Could not add chinchilla, full");

        System.out.println("Removing dog, adding chinchilla.");
        myList.Delete("dog");
        myList.Insert("chinchilla");

        myList.Display();
    }
}
```

here is my code of functions

```
package assignment2;
public class OrderedStringList {
    int length;
    int numUsed;
    String[] storage;
    boolean ordered;

    public OrderedStringList(int size){
        length = size;
        storage = new String[length];
        numUsed = 0;
    }


    public boolean Insert(String value){
        boolean result = false;
                int index = 0;
                if (numUsed < length) {
                    while (index < numUsed) {
                        int compare = storage[index].compareTo(value);
                        if (compare < 0)
                            index++;
                    }
                    moveItemsDown(index);
                    storage[index] = value;
                    numUsed++;
                    result = true;
                }
                return result;
    }
    private void moveItemsDown(int start){
        int index;
        for (index = numUsed-1; index >=start; index--){
            storage[index+1] = storage[index];
        }
    }

    private void moveItemsUp(int start){
        int index;
        for (index = start; index < numUsed-1; index++){
            storage[index] = storage[index+1];
        }
    }

    public boolean Find(String value){
        return (FindIndex(value) >= 0);
    }

    private int FindIndex(String value) {
        int result = -1;
        int index = 0;
        boolean found = false;
        while ((index < numUsed) && (!found)) {
            found = (value.equals(storage[index]));
            if (!found)
                index++;
        }
        if (found)
            result = index;
        return result;
    }

    public boolean Delete(String value){
        boolean result = false;
        int location;
        location = FindIndex(value);
        if (location >= 0) {
            moveItemsUp(location);
            numUsed--;
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void Display() {
        int index;
        System.out.println("list Contents: ");
        for (index = 0; index < numUsed; index++) {
            System.out.println(index+" "+storage[index]);
        }
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void DisplayNoLF() {
        int index;
        System.out.println("list Contents: ");
        for (index = 0; index < numUsed; index++) {
            System.out.print(storage[index]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println("-------------");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public int Size(){
        return numUsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger or put some println statements inside of your `Insert(...)` method to see what's going on, especially in that while loop. I think the key issue here is not the solution to this isolated problem, but that you will want to learn how to debug this and similar problems for the future. And the key to that is knowing what is going on inside your program as it runs.

Comment: Posting one's homework here for us to solve is generally frowned upon...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're getting caught in an infinite loop in the while statement of your Insert function. Consider this piece of code:

```
while (index < numUsed) {
    int compare = storage[index].compareTo(value);
    if (compare < 0)
        index++;
}
```

What happens if `compare >= 0` for `index = 0`? Index doesn't increment upwards, then the while loop is called again on `index = 0`, ad infinitum. You need to increment index outside of the if statement and put a different condition in your if statement.

Comment: Note: This can be easily spotted using a debugger, as proposed in HovercraftFullOfEels answer

Comment: ^^ Absolutely. Try that next time you run into this sort of problem.

Comment: i did not give it a try, but if i just see the code. i don't think it enters the while loop. Correct me if i am wrong!!

Comment: index and numUsed are both 0. How is it entering while?

Comment: Even if it did enter that loop, it's going to throw an exception trying to access an array of `null`s.

Comment: You do have a point Robin... what's stopping up his code here could be somewhere else. But this has major potential to cause an inf loop too.

Comment: It does not enter the while loop whe he inserts dog. But when he insert cat it does enter and never get out. @Halogen got the correct point but on the second call of insert method. +1

Comment: so i got my script running, but im having issues with it alphabetizing the inputed words. what should go in the for loop to make this take inputs 1 2 and 3 and put them in alphabetical order?

Comment: You're on the right track with the code you've got... My guess is that you might not be shifting things the right way. I recommend using a debugger to figure out exactly how things are going wrong, so you can find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
            while (index < numUsed && storage[index].compareTo(value) < 0) {
                    index++;
            }
```

solved my problem by doing this. i simply removed the for loop and added an extra requirement on the while loop.

Comment: Glad you worked things out! If my answer helped you, please accept it for the next poor soul that comes through here with a similar problem.